# Moving div with jQuery under parent's sibling

Tags: jquery

I'd like to move .tiletitle between .date and .department. I tried using e.g. $(".tiletitle").appendTo($(".oneline")) but there are multiple .oneline elements on the page. How do I target the parent's sibling and put it between .date and .department?`

```
<div class="sub-section">
<div>
<div class="tiletitle">Title</div>
</div>
<div class="oneline">
<div class="section-field date">01 May 2022</div>
<div class="section-field department">Cleaning</div>
<div class="section-field location">New York, NY</div>
<div class="section-field country">USA</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$('.sub-section .date').after(function() {
  return $(this).closest('.sub-section').find('.tiletitle')
})
```

This should also ensure that it works inside you have multiple sub-sections

**Demo**

```js
$('.sub-section .date').after(function() {
  return $(this).closest('.sub-section').find('.tiletitle')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub-section">
  <div>
    <div class="tiletitle">Title</div>
  </div>
  <div class="oneline">
    <div class="section-field date">01 May 2022</div>
    <div class="section-field department">Cleaning</div>
    <div class="section-field location">New York, NY</div>
    <div class="section-field country">USA</div>
  </div>
</div>
```